# how to make jquery grid header non clickable?

Tags: jquery, gridview, header

I have a gridview in jquery modal window. this grid displays different results depending upon the user selection on page.
hence the div is populated at runtime with a dataset and colum headers.

I am highlighting the clicked row as below

```
$('#imyGrid tr').click(function() {
        $('#<%=myGrid.ClientID%> tr').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

    });
```

and highlighting the hover as

```
$('#<%=myGrid.ClientID%> tr').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });

    $('#<%=myGrid.ClientID%> tr').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");

    });
```

But this makes the header row also clickable and hover also changes the style. How can I make header row as non clickable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selectors:

```
$('#<%=myGrid.ClientID%> tr:not(:first)')
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/wWAms/)

---

**EDIT:**
To make both header and footer rows unclickable, you can combine [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors:

```
$('#<%=myGrid.ClientID%> tr:not(:first,:last)')
```

Comment: tried this but all it did was highlight/select only the cell which is clicked/hovered. Also it stoped only the first cell of header from getting clicked/hovered.

Comment: @user626309: It sounds to me like you've spelled `tr` wrong - are you using the above code but with `td` by mistake?

Comment: no if i remove the not first it works fine for me and yes it is tr :( not sure y it's behaving a little weird .. getting on my nerves..

Comment: @user626309: Can you set up a jsfiddle example to replicate the problem you're having? Based on your original question, `not(:first)` should work fine (and _does_ work fine in the example I posted).

Comment: THANKS.  Can I do the same for header and footer both together?

Comment: @user626309: You most certainly can - I've updated my answer :)